# Problemas de codificación en Android usando SQLite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación de alimentos en Android Studio e importe una base de datos SQL(Inserto datos con phpMyadmin) a SQLite, que uso en Android Studio. El problema viene cuando hago las consultas e imprimo datos en TextViews. Los caracteres con acentos(á é í ó ú) o la ñ, los muestra algo así.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debería ser "Colación","Densamente energéticos","Carga energética media", no con esos símbolos.
¿Como puedo hacer para mostrarlos correctamente?

Comment: Es posible que sea la codificación de la base de datos

Comment: Asegúrese de que tu base de datos es charset UTF8.

Comment: ¿Como estas obteniendo los datos de tu Bd?

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser que la codificación definida para tu base de datos sea diferente "UTF-8", puedes cambiar la codificación, pero aquí posiblemente necesitarías exportar la base de datos a una con la codificación  "UTF-8".

Te sugiero que antes de mostrar los textos en tu `TextView`, cambies su codificación a "UTF+8" de esta forma:

```
 String textoCorrecto = new String(valorOriginalTexto.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Perdon por contestar tan tarde, ya lo intente lo que me dijiste pero aun así me sigue arrojando el mismo resultado en el TextView. pero gracias.

Comment: @Santidelric agrega el código de como agregas los textos y te ayudamos.

Comment: Encontré una solución, la dejo en las respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré en un foro la siguiente linea de código.

```js
public String Codificador(String cadena) {

        byte[] ptext = cadena.getBytes(ISO_8859_1);
        String resultado = new String(ptext,UTF_8);

        return resultado;
    }
```

Me sirvió, antes de mostrar los textos, uso esta función y resuelve el problema con los acentos y "ñ".

Comment: Selecciona esta respuesta como la correcta, revisa [tour], saludos.